# Abstract algebra. splitting field

Tags: splitting-field

Find the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial $x^6-7$ over $F_{3}$ (the field with $3$ elements).

Here, $x^6-7$|${x^6}^2-7^2 = x^{12}-1$  where $7^2 = 1\mod 3$
After this step, I couldn't make anything. How can I continue for solution? or if this step is wrong, what is the way to solve this question?

Thank you

Comment: please show your work! otherwise, someone will down-vote and you're much less likely to get help, as we won't know what's confusing you.

Comment: I have edited @peter a g. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x^6-7=(x+1)^3(x+2)^3$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. So the degree is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The splitting field over $\Bbb{F}_3$ is a field $\Bbb{F}_{3^q}$. Let's check; $P(X)=X^6-7$ has $\pm 1$ as roots in $\Bbb{F}_3$ because $(\pm 1)^6=1\equiv 7\pmod{3}$

Now we have in $\Bbb{F}_3$ (remember that $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3$)

$$(X-1)^3(X+1)^3=(X^2-1)^3=X^6-1=X^6-7$$

And so our polynomial have two distinct roots of multiplicity $3$ in $\Bbb{F}_3$ and the degree is $1$

Comment: Thank you for your interest @marwalik. But how can i show that 1 is root in  $F_3$

Comment: I edited for more details answering your question